# docker: flag provided but not defined

Tags: docker, makefile, dockerfile, dep

I am using [prometheus-postgresql-adapter](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter) for my project and I am trying to run it in Docker.

And I am going through all of their documentation:

```
go get -u github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter

dep ensure

make
```

When i wrote `make` command it threw me this error:

> GOOS=mingw64_nt-10.0 GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -installsuffix cgo --ldflags '-w' -o prometheus-postgresql-adapter main.go
>   cmd/go: unsupported GOOS/GOARCH pair mingw64_nt-10.0/amd64
>   make: *** [prometheus-postgresql-adapter] Error 2

so i ran it as `make OS=windows`

then

```
make docker-image

make docker-push ORGANIZATOIN=myusername
```

But when I am trying to run that image with this code:

```
 docker run --name prometheus_postgresql_adapter --link pg_prometheus -d -p 9201:9201 \
 timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter:master \
 -pg-host=pg_prometheus \
 -pg-prometheus-log-samples
```

And got that error

> flag provided but not defined: -pg-host

I even changed `-pg-host=pg_prometheus` to `pg-password='mypassword'` since the default host is localhost still get that error:

> flag provided but not defined: -pg-password

when I am trying to remove `-pg-host` or `-pg-password` and let only the `pg-prometheus-log-samples` still get that error":

> flag provided but not defined: -pg-prometheus-log-samples

Anyone has any idea why is not recognizing these flag values?

Also i tried writing `-pg-password='mypassword'` as `-pg-password=mypassword` and even `-pg-password mypassword` but still the same error comes up.

p.s. I am doing all of this in windows

Answer (score -1):

Here,

you need to have all your containers in one docker network. So create one, say named psgs:

```
sudo docker network create psgs
```

After that, you run your containers with the --net=psgs to indicate what docker network you want them run in.

Finally, the adapter seems to expect parameters with the pg.* pattern instead of pg-* pattern.

```
sudo docker run --net=psgs --name pg_prometheus -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=paparazzi timescale/pg_prometheus:master postgres -csynchronous_commit=off

sudo docker run --net=psgs --name prometheus_postgresql_adapter --link pg_prometheus -d -p 9201:9201 timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter:master -pg.host pg_prometheus -pg.password paparazzi
```